# How to clear the recent files list in Adobe Acrobat Professional DC on Mac?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat, plist

Does anyone how to go about clearing the "recent files" list in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC on Mac OS X?   As soon as the application opens, a list of recently opened PDFs is displayed.   I know there is a Clear Files option at the bottom left, but by the time the link is clickable, I already have the spinning beach ball of death and the application hangs.

I figure that there has to be a .plist file somewhere in the filesystem where all of these settings are stored, but when I google this issue all of the various posts I am coming across seem to be referring to this issue on Windows (which involves making a registry edit).   Obviously this is not an option considering I am using a Mac.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro_x86_9.0.plist (or find the one comparable to your version)

it's a .plist which contains (among other things) the recent files list..

it can be modified (if you've got correct permissions set), via terminal, or textwrangler, plist edit pro, or various other plist editors...

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get to work today and let you know if this fixes the issue I am having.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry that did not seem to work.